# Non-Linear Diophantine Equation in Two Variables

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, diophantine-equations, prime-factorization

How many solutions are there in $\mathbb{N}\times \mathbb{N}$ to the equation $\dfrac{1}{x} + \dfrac{1}{y} = \dfrac{1}{1995}$ ? I could solve till I got to the point where $1995^2$ is equal to the product of two variables but I couldn't sort out the pairs of factors solving the equation.
Help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/977926/dfrac1a-dfrac1b-dfrac1c-a-b-c-in-mathbbn-with-no-common-factor-fi/977944#977944